# Generate hash for create_resources from two arrays

Tags: ruby, puppet

I need to create quite a lot of resources, more precisely permission sets for RabbitMQ vhosts.

I'd like to create these from 2 hiera lookups. 2 arrays holding the users and the vhosts.

```
$users = [user1, user2, user3]
$resources = [resource1, resource2, resource3]
```

Should become:

```
$myhashes = {
'user1@resource1' => { 
    },
'user1@resource2' => { 
    },
'user1@resource3' => { 
    },
'user2@resource1' => { 
    },
'user2@resource2' => { 
    },
'user2@resource3' => { 
    },
'user3@resource1' => { 
    },
'user3@resource2' => { 
    },
'user3@resource3' => { 
    },
}
```

This hash could then be fed to create_resources. I have no idea how to go about this in Puppet or Ruby. It's no trouble creating resources from one array, but when I need each entry in that array to hold data from another array I get lost.

Comment: What should the "user1@resource1" hash contain, the array [user1,resource1]?  Also, what type of data are the user and resource objects?

Comment: It's of the type rabbitmq_user_permissions form the official rabbitmq puppet module. They contain permissions for a given vhost on a rabbit node/cluster.
They are strings.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided on how to do the the combining part:

```
myHashes = {}
users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
resources = ["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"]

users.each.with_index do |user, i|
        myHashes["#{user}@#{resources[i]}"] = {}

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it in puppet:

```
$users.each |String $user| {
  $resources.each |String $vhost| {
    rabbitmq_user_permissions {"${user}@${vhost}":
                    configure_permission => '.*',
                    read_permission      => '.*',
                    write_permission     => '.*',}
                        }
                      }
```